# Exercise with Oauth2 flow's - need page with simulator

Tags: oauth2

I want to practice connections of some of OAuth2 flows(user agent, webserver, device etc.) Have you guys know some pages when I can simulate flow types as IDP - I expect that salesforce will be my service provider?